# Cache data on cluster using EJB 3.1 and jboss

Tags: java, caching, jboss, ejb, cluster-computing

I am looking for best solution for cache data in application which will be running on big cluster with multiple JVM. I need to store let's say "value_to_cache" in cache and could compare it on another JVM(most probably) with other values and when needed remove/update(or remove and creating new).  Application will be developing with Java - EJB 3.1 technology and deployed on Jboss 6 or 7.
I was googling for answer so i found:
hibernate with JPA
Infinispan
HAPartition Service

I was hoping for strict answer but couldn't find one. So my question is what is best way to do it? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Infinispan** is the default cache provider on **JBoss 7**. If you want a solution that comes with the application server, than you'll have to stick to this framework.

For **JPA entities** the [second-level cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjia.html) is already there (effectively a predefined Infinispan cache). Just follow the [JPA reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingtheInfinispansecondlevelcache) to get started.

You can also create a custom **Infinispan** cache, if you need a more generic solution. Assuming you're running the `ha` profile in the `domain` mode on JBoss 7 (basic clustering mode):

```
   <profile name="ha"> 
   ...
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="cluster">
     ...
     <cache-container name="myCacheCont" default-cache="myCache">
       <!-- Adjust replication settings below (sync/async etc.) -->
       <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
       <replicated-cache name="myCache" mode="SYNC" batching="true">
          <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
       </replicated-cache>
     </cache-container>
    </subsystem> 
   ...
   </profile>
```

A cache reference can be obtained through a standard `@Resource` lookup in such case:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB implements SomeService {

    @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/myCacheCont")  
    private org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer container;  
    ...
    void doSomethingWithCache() {
       org.infinispan.Cache cache = container.getCache("myCache");
       ...    
       cache.put(...); // Data will be replicated to different nodes, if configured properly
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `org.infinispan` as a module dependency in your project.

Comment: thanks for answer but i have 1 more additional question: what about jboss version? should i use newest 7.1.1 Final AS or 6.1.0 AS and in short/simply why ?

Comment: Check out their [FAQ](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/faq): EAP-6.1.0 is actually JBoss 7.2.0.Final, so you should probably use that.

Comment: i will not use EAP in production bcs of licence (we need free server and EAP 6.1.0 final requires subscription). I meant 6.1.0 Aplication server (not Enterprise Application Platform)

Comment: I meant EAP-6.1.0.Alpha, which is based on JBoss 7.2.0.Final. It doesn't require a subscription (Beta does). Read the FAQ linked in my previous comment.

Comment: so if i am right u are suggesting that EAP 6.1.0 Alpha is better than AS 7.2.0 and i should use it ?

Comment: EAP 6.1.0 Alpha _IS_ AS 7.2.0 Final :) (yes, you should use it)